# why loading JNI in java is done in static initializer?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

In many examples of using JNI, I see something like:

```
class SampleClass {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("somelib");
    }
    ...
}
```

What is the purpose of this special syntax? why using this (and not just in the class constructor or something like that?

Comment: Wouldn't call it special syntax per se. All initialization of static fields could be  done using it, and have seen classloader- or configuration-based scenarios where that was used too. It's generally invoking code that you want "per-class", not per-instance.

Comment: Because (1) you only want to do it once, and (2) it's already too late in the constructor. There might be static native methods, or instance native methods in the base class, or ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will get the best answer from the book:

[Java™ Native Interface: Programmer’s Guide and Specification, The](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javatm-native-interface/0201325772/ch02.html)

Where you can read:

> Before the native method print can be called, the native library that
> implements print must be loaded. In this case, we load the native
> library  in the static initializer of the HelloWorld class. The Java
> virtual machine automatically runs the static initializer before
> invoking any methods in the HelloWorld class, thus ensuring that the
> native library is loaded before the print native method is called.

In general, nothing prevents you from loading library inside method of a class. Method, that is not `static`. But in that case, you have to make sure that you load library (by calling method that invokes load or loadLibrary) before you call any native method.

Also, if you want to load another version of library, without playing with multiple ClassLoaders, you can always use wrapper code. This way, you can dynamically switch between native code implementations.

Take a look here: [dynamic loading of library in JNI](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo018)

Comment: last line "dynamic loading of library in JNI" link becomes 404

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason not to, however usually you want to load native libraries only once. The easiest way to achieve that is through static initializer. Otherwise you'd need to implement your own mechanism to prevent it from happening multiple times. See [Is it possible to load different versions of the same DLL in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678421/is-it-possible-to-load-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-java) for re-loading library.

Another reason is that you wouldn't be capable of providing static methods using native code.