# Why *.so files are loaded as static code?

Tags: android

I'm using opencv4android,such as below.Most of the tutorials I've read indicate that the *.so file should be placed in a static code block. Why not use singleton mode and load only when used?

```
 static{
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [official Android documentation about JNI](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#native-libraries) they say:

> If you have only one class with native methods, it makes sense for the call to System.loadLibrary to be in a static initializer for that class. Otherwise you might want to make the call from Application so you know that the library is always loaded, and always loaded early.

Also you can look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46538504/1515907).

Answer (score 1):

Well, this approach is to ensure it's really only loaded **once**. There is nothing wrong using a singleton, since your library will be loaded fine. However, you need to make sure to load it once, so implement your singleton properly. Besides that, using `static` you are guaranteed (or not when loading fails) that the library is loaded before you can actually call it's  methods.

E.g. the following will work fine as well:

```
boolean loaded = false;
Object mutex = new Object();

public static void load() {
    synchronized(mutex) {
        if (!loaded) {
            System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
            loaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But personally, I still would stick with the `static` block.